# How to keep indexes when sum by columns based on grouped_by in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset where each `ID` has 6 corresponding rows. I want to this dataset grouped by the column `ID` and sum aggregate using sum. I wrote this piece of code:

```
col = [col for col in train.columns if col not in ['Month', 'ID']]
train.groupby('ID')[col].sum().reset_index()
```

Everything works fine except that I lose column ID. Now, Unique ID from my initial database disappeared and instead I have just enumerated ids from 0 up to the number of rows in the resulting dataset. I want to keep initial indexes, because I will need to merge this dataset with another further. How I can deal with this problem? Thanks for helping very much!

P.S: deleting reset_index() has no effect

P.S: You can see two problems on the images. On first image there is original database. You can see 6 entries for each ID. On the second image there is a databased which is a result from the grouped statement. First problem: IDs are not the same as in the original table. Second problem: the sum over 6 months for each ID is not correct.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: Why don't you either just take the result from your groupby statement and assign it to `df_groupbed` and keep `train` as is, or just keep the index in another reference `index = train.index`? After grouping and aggregating you cannot have the original index from the result - you lose that information due to aggregation.

Comment: And how then I will be able to create dataframe where in first column I will have original indexes (each row is unique index) and in other columns I will have the result from aggregating?

Comment: `index = train['ID'].unique()`
`col = [col for col in train.columns if col not in ['Month', 'ID']]`
`train = train.groupby('ID')[col].sum().reset_index()`
`train['ID'] = index`

Is this right?

Comment: Wait - so what you want is just a column `ID`? In that case `reset_index()` is exactly what you want.

Comment: I want a table like in the second screenshot but with correct amounts of sum and original IDs.

Comment: You don't need that list `col`.. you can just call `base1.drop(['MONTH', 'ID', axis=1).sum()` and that's it.

Comment: *typo `base1.drop(['MONTH', 'ID'], axis=1).sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you group a data frame by some columns, those columns become your new index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create data

n = 6; m = 3
col_id = np.hstack([['id-'+str(i)] * n for i in range(m)]).reshape(-1, 1)
np.random.shuffle(col_id)
data = np.random.rand(m*n, m) 
columns = ['v'+str(i+1) for i in range(m)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df['ID'] = col_id

# Group by ID

print(df.groupby('ID').sum())
```

Will simply give you

```
            v1        v2        v3
ID                                
id-0  2.099219  2.708839  2.766141
id-1  2.554117  2.183166  3.914883
id-2  2.485505  2.739834  2.250873
```

If you just want the column `ID` back, you just have to `reset_index()`

```
print(df.groupby('ID').sum().reset_index())
```

which will leave you with

```
     ID        v1        v2        v3
0  id-0  2.099219  2.708839  2.766141
1  id-1  2.554117  2.183166  3.914883
2  id-2  2.485505  2.739834  2.250873
```

**Note:**

`groupby` will sort the resulting DataFrame by its index. If you don't want that for any reason just set `sorted=False` (see also the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html))

```
print(df.groupby('ID', sorted=false).sum())
```

Comment: 1. I don't know why, but when I'm trying to run your code everything works fine, but when I run the same for my dataset, the reset_index doesn't works and simply enumerate indexes from zero and further.

2. I have just noticed, that the sum() function doesn't work properly also. I have manually calculated sums for some indexes and there are mismatches. What can be wrong?

Comment: I have added 2 screenshot which demonstrates my problem and the description to them. Maybe this will help to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @DmitrijBurlaj See what happens as you print out your  `sorted(base1.ID.unique())`.

Comment: On the original base1 or after grouping?

Comment: @DmitrijBurlaj No, before that. Because I am sure `base1.ID` contains values `[1, 2, 3, 4, ..]`

Comment: So, the sums are correct, they are just sorted in ascending order?

Comment: @DmitrijBurlaj As you can see, `groupby` will return you the sum of all your unique `ID` values and further sort the data frame's index.

Comment: @DmitrijBurlaj Exactly. You can use my code from above and just change `df['ID'] = col_id` to `df['ID'] = col_id[::-1]` which will just reverse the list and you'll see that after grouping your indices are sorted.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! I don't know that it sorts the data! You helped me very much!

Comment: @DmitrijBurlaj You're welcome. You can actually turn sorting off in case it improves the performance by setting `groupby('ID', sorted=False)`.  See also [`groupby()` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `reset_index()` you can simply use the keyword argument `as_index`: `df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)`
This will preserve column `ID` in the resulting `DataFrameGroupBy`, as described in [`groupby()`'s doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

> as_index : boolean, default True
>
> For aggregated output, return object with group labels as the index. Only relevant for DataFrame input. as_index=False is effectively “SQL-style” grouped output